# lowdb: queries are synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, promise

I'm using `lowdb` in `Node.js`:

https://github.com/typicode/lowdb

I don't understand this sentence:

> the execution of methods is lazy, that is, execution is deferred until .value() is called.

If I have this code:

```
const post = db.get('posts').find({ id: postId }).value();
```

may I use `post` just after that line?

Comment: `storage object, by default lowdb/lib/file-sync` - looks synchronous

Comment: The same for the memory storage, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it looks like it.

The sentence means that adding `.get()` and `.find()` methods only refines the eventual query, but by calling `.value()` the query actually gets executed.

Given the example code, it seems like `.value()` actually gives you a value, and not a Promise to a value or anything like that.